# Cравнение в линейном списке

Tags: c++

Недавно разобрался с линейным списком и у меня возник вопрос. Я обьявил текстовую строку (`char s[] = "1234566\n";`), загнал ее в список. Хочу сравнивать элементы списка (1, 2...), но никак не получается. Компилятор выдавал разные ошибки, в основном - не стыковка типов, вот код функции сравнения:

```
// запоминаем адрес начального элемента

Node * temp = head;

while (temp != 0)
{
    if ((int)temp==1) 
    {
        cout<<"Habe sie\n";
    }

    temp = temp->next;
}
```

`if((int)temp==1)` - что сюда писать? чтобы при прохождении цикла комп увидел в 1234566 две шестерки(66) и выдал текст? Если можно, объясните по подробней. Спасибо.

Comment: я уже точно не помню, как там и что в с++, но у меня такое подозрение, что указатель сравнивать со значением в данном контексте не имеет смысла. скорее всего должно быть что-то вроде if(((int)temp->getValue==6&&(int)temp->next->getValue==6)){cout<<"habe sien";}

Answer (score 1):

```
Node * temp = head;

while (temp != NULL) // или null_ptr
{
   if (temp->value==1) 
   {
     cout<<"Habe sie\n";
   }

   temp = temp->next;
}
```

Примерно так. Не забывайте, что `temp` - это всего лишь указатель. Т.е. адрес в памяти. Адреса в памяти вообще не очень осмысленно сравнивать, кроме одного случая - проверить, что оба указателя ссылаются на один объект (зачастую это бывает один из крайних случаев, который нужно обрабатывать отдельно). Поэтому нужно сравнивать `temp->value` (или как оно там у Вас называется), т.е. сами значения, которые хранятся в каждом из элементов списка.

P.S. если у вас Сишный стиль, то для поиска в строке придется искать ф-цию [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/). Если используете C++ и `std::string` для строк, то можно или вручную перебирать, или 
[`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: Не, не работает:   '==' : 'Node *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

Comment: Дайте описание структуры `Node`

Comment: На выходе не числа, а похоже адреса ячеек памяти(00094490..)

 struct Node  
 {   
  char data; 
  Node *next; // Ссылка на следущий элемент списка
 };


и тут ошибка(нет равенства):

 void List::Rmv()
 {
  // запоминаем адрес головного элемента
  Node * temp = head; 
  
  while(temp != NULL)
  {  
   if(temp->next==temp)
   {
    cout<<"Habe sie"<<temp<<' '<<temp->next<<'\n';
   }
   else
   {
    cout<<"Habe Nicht"<<temp<<' '<<temp->next<<'\n';
   }

   temp=temp->next;
  }
 }

Comment: По моим догадкам, нет сравнения значений, находящихся по данным адресам, а происходит сравнение самих адресов...

Comment: Значит нужно сравнивать `temp->data` с Вашим образцом. Если же не `char data`, а `char *data`, то см. выше - используйте ф-цию `strstr` для поиска подстроки в строке.

Comment: Не,(похоже Вы не поняли меня) мне нужно сравнить два соседних элемента в строке допустим "123356", 33-соседнии-> первую тройку я оставлю, а другую удалю.... А я никак не могу почему-то элементы сравнить(на выводе у меня temp->data -мои элементы, а temp и temp->next какие-то адреса....)

Answer (score 1):

Если temp->value - символ, то при сравнении не приводите его значение к типу int, вы же так получите его аски-код. сравнивайте символы

```
if (temp->value=='1')
```

задача нечетко поставлена - вм нужно убрать все повторения символов? ну сравните текущий элемент со следующим, что то вроде

```
if (temp->value == temp->next->value )
    temp->next=temp->next->next;
```